# Jquery custom trigger anchor tag

Tags: javascript, jquery, triggers

Hello every one I am creating custom multistep form but when I click on next button it can't `trigger` related `<a>` anchor tag ( auto click )

Please help me to resolve my issue

**Thanks in Advance**

```js
$(function() {
  $("#nextBtn").click(function() {
    var $tabs = $("li");
    $tabs.each(function() {

      var activeTab = $(this).hasClass("active");
      if (activeTab == true) {
        //var activeAnch = $(this).children().attr("href");
        alert($(this).next('li').children().attr("href"));
        var nextId = $(this).next('li').children().attr("id");
        //$("#"+nextId).click();// trigger click to #menu 1 <a>
      }
    });
  });
});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <title>Bootstrap Case</title>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
  <ul class="nav nav-pills">
    <li class="active"><a data-toggle="pill" href="#home">Home</a></li>
    <li><a data-toggle="pill" href="#menu1">Menu 1</a></li>
    <li><a data-toggle="pill" href="#menu2">Menu 2</a></li>
    <li><a data-toggle="pill" href="#menu3">Menu 3</a></li>
  </ul>

  <div class="tab-content">
    <div id="home" class="tab-pane fade in active">
      <h3>HOME</h3>
      <span>Form 1</span>
    </div>
    <div id="menu1" class="tab-pane fade">
      <h3>Menu 1</h3>
      <span>Form 2</span>
    </div>
    <div id="menu2" class="tab-pane fade">
      <h3>Menu 2</h3>
      <span>Form 3</span>
    </div>
    <div id="menu3" class="tab-pane fade">
      <h3>Menu 3</h3>
      <span>Form 4</span>
    </div>
  </div>

  <button id="nextBtn">Next</button>

</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have done some changes to Parvez Rahman's answer. You don't need to click internally on an element through javascript. I guess that's like an antipattern.

You could use bootstrap functionality to show the next tab with tab function instead of doing a click on the element.

```js
$(function() {
  $("#nextBtn").click(function() {
    $('li.active').next().find('a').tab("show"); //show tab of the next li
  });
});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <title>Bootstrap Case</title>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
  <ul class="nav nav-pills">
    <li class="active"><a data-toggle="pill" href="#home">Home</a></li>
    <li><a data-toggle="pill" href="#menu1">Menu 1</a></li>
    <li><a data-toggle="pill" href="#menu2">Menu 2</a></li>
    <li><a data-toggle="pill" href="#menu3">Menu 3</a></li>
  </ul>

  <div class="tab-content">
    <div id="home" class="tab-pane fade in active">
      <h3>HOME</h3>
      <span>Form 1</span>
    </div>
    <div id="menu1" class="tab-pane fade">
      <h3>Menu 1</h3>
      <span>Form 2</span>
    </div>
    <div id="menu2" class="tab-pane fade">
      <h3>Menu 2</h3>
      <span>Form 3</span>
    </div>
    <div id="menu3" class="tab-pane fade">
      <h3>Menu 3</h3>
      <span>Form 4</span>
    </div>
  </div>

  <button id="nextBtn">Next</button>

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Thanks@prajnavantha

Comment: Really easy and helpful  ..:)

Answer (score 1):

What you have tot do is just

```
$("#nextBtn").click(function() {
    var $nextLi = $('li.active').next('li');
    if ($nextLi.length) $nextLi.find('a:first').click();
});
```

```js
$(function() {
  $("#nextBtn").click(function() {
    var $nextLi = $('li.active').next('li');
    if ($nextLi.length) {
      $nextLi.find('a:first').click();
    } else {
      $('ul.nav a:first').click();
    }
  });
});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <title>Bootstrap Case</title>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
  <ul class="nav nav-pills">
    <li class="active"><a data-toggle="pill" href="#home">Home</a></li>
    <li><a data-toggle="pill" href="#menu1">Menu 1</a></li>
    <li><a data-toggle="pill" href="#menu2">Menu 2</a></li>
    <li><a data-toggle="pill" href="#menu3">Menu 3</a></li>
  </ul>

  <div class="tab-content">
    <div id="home" class="tab-pane fade in active">
      <h3>HOME</h3>
      <span>Form 1</span>
    </div>
    <div id="menu1" class="tab-pane fade">
      <h3>Menu 1</h3>
      <span>Form 2</span>
    </div>
    <div id="menu2" class="tab-pane fade">
      <h3>Menu 2</h3>
      <span>Form 3</span>
    </div>
    <div id="menu3" class="tab-pane fade">
      <h3>Menu 3</h3>
      <span>Form 4</span>
    </div>
  </div>

  <button id="nextBtn">Next</button>

</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

Please use the below code to achieve this.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#nextBtn").click(function() {
    $('li.active').next().find('a')[0].click();

    //hide the next button    
    $('.nav li a').on('shown.bs.tab', function(e) {
      var $lastEle = $(".nav li:last-child").hasClass('active');
      if ($lastEle) {
        $("#nextBtn").hide();
      }else{
        $("#nextBtn").show();
     }
    });
  });
});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <title>Bootstrap Case</title>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

</head>

<body>
  <ul class="nav nav-pills">
    <li class="active"><a data-toggle="pill" href="#home">Home</a></li>
    <li><a data-toggle="pill" href="#menu1">Menu 1</a></li>
    <li><a data-toggle="pill" href="#menu2">Menu 2</a></li>
    <li><a data-toggle="pill" href="#menu3">Menu 3</a></li>
  </ul>

  <div class="tab-content">
    <div id="home" class="tab-pane fade in active">
      <h3>HOME</h3>
      <span>Form 1</span>
    </div>
    <div id="menu1" class="tab-pane fade">
      <h3>Menu 1</h3>
      <span>Form 2</span>
    </div>
    <div id="menu2" class="tab-pane fade">
      <h3>Menu 2</h3>
      <span>Form 3</span>
    </div>
    <div id="menu3" class="tab-pane fade">
      <h3>Menu 3</h3>
      <span>Form 4</span>
    </div>
  </div>

  <button id="nextBtn">Next</button>

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Thanks @Rahul kumar

Answer (score 1):

Simple use with `[clas='active']` match

```js
$(function() {
$("#nextBtn").click(function() {
var nextId = $("li[class='active']").next('li').children('a').attr("href")
if(nextId){
  $('a[href="'+nextId+'"]').trigger('click');
  }
  else{
  $('ul').children('li').eq(0).children('a').trigger('click');
  
  }
});
});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <title>Bootstrap Case</title>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
  <ul class="nav nav-pills">
    <li class="active"><a data-toggle="pill" href="#home">Home</a></li>
    <li><a data-toggle="pill" href="#menu1">Menu 1</a></li>
    <li><a data-toggle="pill" href="#menu2">Menu 2</a></li>
    <li><a data-toggle="pill" href="#menu3">Menu 3</a></li>
  </ul>
  
  <div class="tab-content">
    <div id="home" class="tab-pane fade in active">
      <h3>HOME</h3>
      <span>Form 1</span>
    </div>
    <div id="menu1" class="tab-pane fade">
      <h3>Menu 1</h3>
      <span>Form 2</span>
    </div>
    <div id="menu2" class="tab-pane fade">
      <h3>Menu 2</h3>
      <span>Form 3</span>
    </div>
    <div id="menu3" class="tab-pane fade">
      <h3>Menu 3</h3>
      <span>Form 4</span>
    </div>
  </div>

<button id="nextBtn">Next</button>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
$(function() {
  $("#nextBtn").click(function() {
    var $tabs = $("li");
    $tabs.each(function() {

      var activeTab = $(this).hasClass("active");
      if (activeTab == true) {
        var secAttr = $(this).next('li').children().attr("href");
        $('a[href="' + secAttr + '"]').tab('show');
        return false;
      }
    });
  });
});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <title>Bootstrap Case</title>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
  <ul class="nav nav-pills">
    <li class="active"><a data-toggle="pill" href="#home">Home</a></li>
    <li><a data-toggle="pill" href="#menu1">Menu 1</a></li>
    <li><a data-toggle="pill" href="#menu2">Menu 2</a></li>
    <li><a data-toggle="pill" href="#menu3">Menu 3</a></li>
  </ul>

  <div class="tab-content">
    <div id="home" class="tab-pane fade in active">
      <h3>HOME</h3>
      <span>Form 1</span>
    </div>
    <div id="menu1" class="tab-pane fade">
      <h3>Menu 1</h3>
      <span>Form 2</span>
    </div>
    <div id="menu2" class="tab-pane fade">
      <h3>Menu 2</h3>
      <span>Form 3</span>
    </div>
    <div id="menu3" class="tab-pane fade">
      <h3>Menu 3</h3>
      <span>Form 4</span>
    </div>
  </div>

  <button id="nextBtn">Next</button>

</body>

</html>
```